# Center align visible columns in row bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center align a div inside a div. Not just a div. Div in bootstrap 4 grid layout.

My template is like this

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6 invisible'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I was expecting is or trying to achieve is since second column inside the row is invisible the first column will become center aligned inside the row.

How can I make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences betwwen two classes I'll mention.

You have to use the second one:

1.`<div class="invisible">*other elements ...*</div>`

1. Just hides your div, but keeps its place.

2.`<div class="d-none">*other elements ...*</div>`

2. Hides your div and removes its place

2nd one will work for you

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer you should use **d-none** class instead of **invisible** class. Note: if you want your div to be appeared in another size, you should use **d-block** class NOT **visible** class